# Valor de caixa de texto de html ser recebido por variavel de javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ola,estou aprendendo javascript e queria saber como faço para o que for digitado na  caixa de texto HTML for impresso na tela em document.write de javascript.

Comment: Você tem algum código pra mostrar? Isso pode ajudar bastante a responder.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, mas utilizando o `document.write` vai fazer com que você reescreva sua página, fazendo com que seus controles sumam.

```js
function writeItDown(btn){
  var suaVariavel = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
  document.write(suaVariavel);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput" /> <button id="myBtn" onclick="writeItDown(this);" >Write</button>
```

A melhor opção seria utilizar um elemento html como um `span` e escrever dentro dele através da propriedade `innerHTML` do elemento. dessa forma:

```js
function escrever(btn){
  var suaVariavel = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
  document.getElementById('meuTextoVaiAqui').innerHTML = suaVariavel;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput" /> <button id="myBtn" onclick="escrever(this);" >Write</button>
<br/><span id="meuTextoVaiAqui"></span>
```

Comment: OBRIGADO ANDRE PAULO.

Answer (score 0):

Pode sempre fazer algo do genero:

HTML:

```
<p>
    //o resultado vai cair aqui
</p>

//com um input
<input type="text" onkeyup="changeResult(this)" />

//ou com uma textarea
<textarea onkeyup="changeResult(this)"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var changeResult = function(element)
{
   document.getElementsByTagName("p") = element.value; 
}
```

E possivel que exista algum erro pois nao testei mas a lógica é essa

Comment: OBRIGADO,SIMÃO LEMOS.

Comment: Se tiver correcta a resposta marca como correta por favor, ou diz o que falhou

Answer (score 0):

Biblioteca

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.class').keyup(function (e) {
       var v1 = (document.getElementById("v1").value);
       $('#v2').text(v1);
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="class" name="v1" id="v1" size="10" /> 
<span id="v2"> </span>>
```

Comment: OBRIGADO LEO CARACCIOLO.